# conversion of DateField to TrieDateField in Solr

Tags: solr, drupal-6

I'm using Apache Solr for powering the search functionality in my Drupal site using a contributed module for drupal named [ApacheSolr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). I'm pretty novice with Solr and have a basic understanding of it, hence wish to convey my apologies in advance if this query sounds outrageous.

I have a date field added through one of drupal's hooks named `ds_myDate` which I initially used for sorting the search results. I decided to use a [date boosting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents), so that the search results are displayed based on relevancy and boosted by their date rather than merely being displayed by the descending order of date. Once I had updated my hook to implement the same by adding a boost field as `recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,ds_myDate),3.16e-11,1,1)` I got a HTTP 400 error stating

> Can't use ms() function on non-numeric legacy date field ds_myDate

Googling for the same suggested that I use a TrieDateField instead of the Legacy DateField to prevent this error. Adding a TrieDate field named `tds_myDate` following the suggested naming convention and implementing the boost as `recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,tds_myDate),3.16e-11,1,1)` did effectively achieve the boosting. However this requires me to reindex all the content (close to 500k records) to populate the new TrieDate field so that I may be able to use it effectively.

I'd request to know if there's an effective workaround than re-indexing all my content such as converting my `ds_myDate` to a TrieDate field like running an alter query on a mysql table field to change its type. Since I'm unfamiliar with how Solr works would request to know if such an option is feasible and what the right thing to do would be for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, once a document has been indexed a certain way and you change the schema, you cannot have the new schema changes be applied to existing documents until those documents are re-indexed.

Please see this previous question - [Does Schema Change need Reindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738615/does-schemachange-need-reindex) for additional details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarity and the links. much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to achieve it by doing a Partial update, but for that you need to be on on Solr 4+ and storing all indexed fields.

Here is how I would go with this:

- Make sure version of Solr is 4+
- Make sure all indexed fields are stored (requirement for partial updates)
- If above two conditions meet, write a script(PHP), which does following:
- 1) Iterate through full Solr index, and for each doc:
- ----a) read value stored in ds_myDate field
- ----b) Convert it to TrieDateField format
- ----c) Push onto Solr, via partial update to only tds_myDate field (see sample query)

Sample query:

`curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"$id","tds_myDate":{"set":$converted_Val}}]'`

For more details on partial updates: http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, in my case the value in both the DateField and TrieDate field would be the same date value in ISO-8601 format. I'll try to give it a shot and let you know.